# Swift Paste Audio File (.mp3, .m4a, etc.) from Clipboard and Save

Tags: swift, paste, audio-recording

EDIT/UPDATE: So I've been messing around with this. When I copy a .mp3 to the UIPasteboard from iMessages on my Mac that I'm running the simulator on, the following code:

```
    @IBAction func pasteboardButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if UIPasteboard.general.hasStrings == true {
            print("strings present")
        }

        if UIPasteboard.general.hasURLs == true {
            print("URL present")
        }

        print("pasteboard items \(UIPasteboard.general.items)")
        print("pasteboard count \(UIPasteboard.general.items.count)")
        print("pasteboard type \(UIPasteboard.general.types)")
        print("pasteboard URL \(UIPasteboard.general.url)")

    }

}
```

yields the following output:

```
strings present
URL present
pasteboard items [["public.url": <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x600001ef9840] = { leaf, size = 116, buf = 0x1201b5000 }>, "public.file-url": <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x60000105c2c0] = { leaf, size = 116, buf = 0x1204f8000 }>]]
pasteboard count 1
pasteboard type ["public.url", "public.file-url"]
pasteboard URL nil
```

So, it seems that it's recognizing the .mp3 file on the pasteboard, but it's type is 'public.url' and won't be case as URL for me to store locally. Checking the [Apple UIPasteboard Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard#2107142) it says "A Uniform Type Identifier (UTI) is frequently used as the key for a representation type. For example, you could use the kUTTypeJPEG UTI (a constant for public.jpeg) as a representation type key for JPEG data."

I'm assuming my 'constant' here is public.url, but I don't know what the equivalent of kUTTypeJPEG UTI representation key would be to cast the copied public.url as URL so that line

```
print("pasteboard URL \(UIPasteboard.general.url)")
```

doesn't result in nil?

ORIGINAL POST:
I've looked all over and can't find anything to even get me started, so I apologize for no code. But how would I allow a user to paste an .mp3 or .m4a audio file from their clipboard into a UITextField and then save that locally? I'm familiar with storing URL's and handling local AVAssets, just clueless on how I would pull a file type other than a string of text from the clipboard into a container to store locally. Any help is greatly appreciated!